# Cascading Triggers

Tags: mysql, mariadb, stored-procedures, trigger

I'm running MariaDB 10.2.31 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. My data consists 99% of JSON-encoded strings from a remote API.
Example (orders) very much simplified:

```
{
    "id":123,
    "referrer": "webshop",
    "items": [
        {
            "id":456,
            "orderId": 123,
            "amounts": [
                {
                    "id": 789,
                    "orderItemId": 456,
                    "value": 2
                },
                {...},{...}
            ]
        },
        {...},{...}
    ]
}
```

For clarification: Every order can have several items, every item can have several amounts.
These objects can become rather large and diverse so I went with table definitions like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `json` longtext NOT NULL,
    `items` longtext GENERATED ALWAYS AS json_unquote(json_extract(`json`,'$.items') STORED
);
```

Then, to have a table with orderItems I have another table:

```
CREATE TABLE `orderItems` (
    `json` longtext NOT NULL,
    `amounts` longtext GENERATED ALWAYS AS json_unquote(json_extract(`json`,'$.amounts') STORED
);
```

So, all I need to do is to `INSERT` the original JSON-string in column json and trigger a procedure (AFTER INSERT and AFTER UPDATE) like this to have complete data in several tables:

```
SET @items_json = (SELECT items FROM orders WHERE id=param_orderID LIMIT 1);
IF (@items_json!='[]' AND @items_json IS NOT NULL) THEN
    SET @indx = 0;
    REPEAT
        SET @txt=JSON_EXTRACT(@items_json, CONCAT('$[', @indx, ']'));
        IF @txt IS NOT NULL THEN INSERT INTO orderItems (json) VALUES (@txt) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE json=@txt; END IF;
        SET @indx = @indx + 1;
        UNTIL @indx=JSON_LENGTH(@items_json) 
    END REPEAT;
END IF;
```

This works like a charm.

However, when I do the exact same for a "third level" table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `orderItems_amounts` (
    `json` longtext NOT NULL,
    `id` INT(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS json_unquote(json_extract(`json`,'$.id') STORED,
    `orderItemId` INT(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS json_unquote(json_extract(`json`,'$.orderItemId') STORED,
    `value` DECIMAL(10,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS json_unquote(json_extract(`json`,'$.value') STORED,
);
```

the procedure does not INSERT anything because `@txt IS NULL` (I wrestled `column json cannot be NULL` and debugged the heck out of it). When I `INSERT` manually (or via a PHP script) the trigger and procedure works fine just like expected and the same way it works on my "second level" tables.

So, in principle:
INSERT INTO orders TRIGGERS the procedure INSERTING INTO orderItems which event should in turn trigger the same procedure (tablenames etc are dynamic) to INSERT INTO orderItems_amounts.
Again: separately these two steps work fine.

I researched all day and couldn't find anything specific about it. Is it possible, that an INSERT from a procedure does not trigger the INSERT-event? Am I overlooking something entirely different? My suspicion is that the GENERATED columns have something to do with it. But since I don't encounter any problems in the first step (orders -> orderItems) I tend to think this should be okay. Also I found something in the MariaDB docs that the INSERT and UPDATE events are happening after the GENERATING of column values.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1c29a150809a6d37319d61aff6c01173

I had to keep the last step (INSERT INTO orders) **#commented out** because it seems to run forever and then the run fails (in real life no problem). But the principle should be clear. Also, my MariaDB Version is unavailable.

**EDIT AFTER DEBUGGING** 
After hours of debugging and trying to understand what's going on:
I changed a few things about my procedures (both are similar except tablenames to write into etc):

```
SET @items_json = (SELECT `items` FROM `orders` WHERE `id`=param_id LIMIT 1);
IF(TRIM(@items_json)!='[]' AND @items_json IS NOT NULL) THEN
    SET @index = 0;
    REPEAT
        SET @txt=JSON_EXTRACT(@items_json, CONCAT('$[', @index, ']'));
        IF @txt IS NOT NULL THEN
            INSERT INTO `orderItems` (`json`) VALUES (@txt) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `json`=@txt;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO `test` (`json`, `orderItemID`, `colname`) VALUES (@items_json, param_id, 'items');
        END IF;
        SET @index = @index + 1;
        UNTIL (@index=JSON_LENGTH(@items_json) OR @txt IS NULL)
    END REPEAT;
END IF;
```

Things I changed:

- backtick everything (that wasn't the problem but still, let this be a lesson in adhering to conventions even if seemingly unnecessary)
- introducing a conditional statement for the insert so failing inserts get caught somewhere and I can determine what to do with it later. This was just part of my debugging efforts but I will keep it
- UNTIL ... OR @txt IS NULL - during debugging I noticed that @index never grew beyond reasonable values and JSON_LENGTH also was always valid - this did however fix the occasional endless running of the loop

So now I have failed inserts logged in my test-table.
**HOWEVER** if I compare contents of the test-table (failed inserts) with the actual target-table **there are no entries missing!**

This I still don't understand. Are events firing twice? Like once before GENERATED columns are stored and once after?

After running my script for a while (fetching around 2000 orders) it seems that failed inserts happen **ONLY** for orders -> orderItems and **ONLY** if the trigger on table orderItems exists! As soon as I delete that trigger there is nothing being inserted into my test-table.
Since I have several tables I "spread" data to (orderAddresses, orderComments, orderReferences, ...) I can definetly say, the problem occurs **ONLY** as soon as there is another trigger on the table the first trigger and procedure inserted to.

Curious to see if anyone has insight on that.

Comment: Post the trigger as well. In fact, if you can reproduce the phenomena at for example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3 (10.2 seems unavailable) and post back the URL, I'm pretty sure that someone can assist

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1c29a150809a6d37319d61aff6c01173

I had to keep the last step (INSERT INTO orders) #commented out because it seems to run forever. But the principle should be clear.

Comment: There is something fishy with the loop in spreadOrderItems. It appears to loop forever. I tried to remove as much as possible: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9f2c38347a3cda1644843d38fc8ef19a but it still does not terminate. Beats me, let's hope someone with more experience with MySQL procedure  language jumps in.

Comment: Very strange.. Isn't it exactly the same as in the other one?

Comment: Thought: if json IS NULL (and it doesn't get inserted), json_length should also fail.. I remember doing something like where the array length is determined only if json IS NOT NULL and setting it to zero as default. Will fiddle this tomorrow. But in this case the problem was the same. I still think there is no json to extract when the insert fires

Comment: I tried to add COALESCE to handle null in termination condition but to no avail.

Comment: Will go to it with fresh brain tomorrow.  Thank you for your effort. I will try to go very small steps from the ground up and debug.. Which is a pain with procedures...